# Prevent stopping a kotlin stream when an error occured

Tags: kotlin, error-handling, rx-java

I have a question about this stream bellow:

```
        list
            .filter { filter.matchFilter1(it) }
            .flatMap { obj1 ->
                val list2 = transform(obj1)
                list2
                    .filter { filter.matchFilter2(it) }
                    .map { transform2(obj1, it) }
            }
```

When an error occured in the `filter.matchFilter2(it)` the stream stops and I'm not getting filtered the other elements from the list.
Is there a way to handle this, something like the RX `onErrorResumeNext` ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: handle the error in `matchFilter2` and return `false` in case of error

Comment: is there a way to do it without using try, catch ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Standard Library [Result APIs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-result/), namely [`runCatching`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/run-catching.html) and [`recover`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/recover.html) for this:

```kotlin
runCatching { 
    filter.matchFilter2(it)
}.recover { throwable ->
    someDefaultValue
}
```

Or perhaps `runCatching` and then [`getOrNull`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-result/get-or-null.html) + an Elvis operator, if you don't need the throwable itself for your error case:

```kotlin
runCatching {
    filter.matchFilter2(it)
}.getOrNull() ?: defaultValue
```